# Very long compilation time on mbed-cli in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, compilation, mbed

I need to use offline mbed-cli in Eclipse to have debugging capabilities. 
I installed package of mbed-cli software according to the instructions. 
When I try to compile the Blinky example, it takes few minutes to compile all available libraries when this compilation should take a few seconds.

Please look at [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iDd5RLGTRTI) video to see how it works. Just to compare, it should look like [this](https://youtu.be/eZl9HL1mn6Q?t=404).

What should I do to configure it to compile only necessary libraries?
Even if it takes only a few minutes, I still get errors in libraries that don't matter and that causes the compilation to fail.

Answer (score 0):

The initial compilation of an Mbed OS project indeed takes quite a bit as it'll compile the full project, then link it out. Afterwards subsequent compilations should be fast. It does seem from the video that you're compiling only file at the same time, calling `make` with `-j` will run it on multiple cores.

Unfortunately I cannot see what the error is from your video, so if you could add it plus the name of your development board, could help you debug.